# Windows Phone - Persisting an Instance member of a PhoneApplicationPage across pages

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an Instance member in the MainPage.xaml.cs ie in the MainPage class extending from PhoneApplicationPage
When I navigate to another page and back again I want to have the value of the Instance member ... How do i persist across Page calls ?
Have only a couple of pages and the member object class is small

Should I Push into PhoneApplicationService?? and into the State?

Is this the cleanest and best performing way??

First time in Mobile dev ... Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general use, the Page instance will be preserved in RAM - so you don't need to do anything.

However, in tombstoning situations then your page instance will get flushed from RAM.

To preserve a value or a string, the easiest thing to do is to save/load your value to IsolatedStorageSettings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=VS.95).aspx

You can use the OnNavigateTo method to load this, and the OnNavigatedFrom method to save it.

If you need to persist a larger or more complicated object, then you can use JSON or XML to serialize/deserialize the object - and you can look at using more general storage techniques - e.g. files in IsolatedStorage or a database solution like SQLCE, SQLite or Sterling

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the instance member will get destroyed during navigation unless the page is removed from backstack or application is tombstoned. you don't have to write extra line of code in order to keep the instance member alive. So you don't have to store it in PhoneApplicationService's State.

Comment: But you SHOULD be saving them in the state nevertheless - because nothing will save those variables from 4 pages ago automatically when the app gets Deactivated.